# Tengo un array de numeros y quiero buscar en otro array y cuantas veces se repiten

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array con numeros

```
var arrayoption = [1,2,3,4];
```

En mi otro array que es del siguiente modo

```
var arrayparent = [0,1,2,2];
```

Lo que trato de hacer es que los numeros ue se encuentran en arrayoption sean buscados en el arrayparent y dandome como repuesta la cantidad que se repiten.
He buscado formas de contar repetidos y he conseguido algo

```
const cantidadparent = arrayparent.reduce((countparent, parent)=>{
    countparent[parent] = (countparent[parent] || 0) +1;
    return countparent;
  }, {});

console.log(cantidadparent);
```

Cuenta los que estan en mi arrayparent y me devuelve esto

[image: repuesta reduce]

Y estuve tratando de hacer una mezcla de ambos array y que me devuelva de la siguiente manera.

[image: repuesta deseada]

Seria de mucha ayuda si alguien pudiera guiarme con este tema. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una vez tienes el `array` con el número de repeticiones, yo en este caso lo he hecho con `foreach`, puedes recorrer el array de referencia con `foreach` y rellenarlo en base a los datos que tienes en el `array` con el número de repeticiones.

```js
var arrayoption = [1,2,3,4];
var arrayparent = [0,1,2,2];

var repetidos = {}, resultados = {}; 
arrayparent.forEach(function(numero){
  repetidos[numero] = (repetidos[numero] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(repetidos);
arrayoption.forEach(function(item, index){
   if (repetidos[arrayoption[index]]) {
      resultados[item] = repetidos[arrayoption[index]];
   } else {
      resultados[item] = 0;
   }
});
console.log(resultados);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vaya, creo que se me han adelantado, pero creo que las dos respuestas van en la misma línea. Te pongo mi forma de resolverlo, y evidentemente sería también con un `forEach`, aunque también se podría resolver con `Map` o `for...in`.

```js
var arrayoption = [1,2,3,4];
var arrayparent = [0,1,2,2];

var res = [];
arrayoption.forEach(function(elementoBuscado){

        var cantidad = 0;

        arrayparent.forEach(function(elementoAComprobar){

            if(elementoAComprobar == elementoBuscado){

                cantidad++;

            }

        })

        res.push(cantidad);

})

console.log(res);
```